# How to get data from php file in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-http

I have .php file with content:

test.php

```
<?php
    echo 'a';
```

And this is my Angular 2 component.

app.component.ts

```
import {Component, AfterViewInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter,
     ElementRef, ChangeDetectorRef, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, Response, Jsonp} from '@angular/http';

import {JsonData} from './json-data';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
    public data: any;

    public constructor(private http: Http, public element: ElementRef, 
                    private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        this.element = this.element.nativeElement;
    }

    public getData() {
           this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/test.php').map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .subscribe(result => this.data = result);
            console.dir(this.data);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
         this.getData();
    }
}
```

I want to recieve 'a' as response, but my response contains everything in php file:

```
<?php
     echo 'a';
```

Can I get only 'a' ?

Comment: try echo json_encode("a")

Answer (score 0):

**First:** Http calls are Async in Angular2.

Therefore you cannot do `console.dir(this.data);` after making a call. You need to wait for the data to get back from the server.

If you want to log the data you need to change the subscription. For multiple lines of code you can put braces around "`this.data = result`":

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/test.php').map((response: Response) => response.json())
    .subscribe(result => {
        this.data = result;
        console.dir(this.data);
    );
```

**Second:** If your response returns everything in the php file ("`<?php echo 'a';`") then your php server is not running.. Do you have something like wamp server installed? (assuming you are on windows.)

Hope this will help you a bit.

Comment: Thank you! your answer helps me to partially solve problem. Now "this.data" true in subscription, but it's empty when I call console.log(this.data); in ngOnInit() or any other place...
Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: if you call http://localhost:3000/test.php from your browser. what does it return?

Comment: I already changed localhost:3000 to localhost:8080 (xampp server), and in result localhost:8080/test.php call browser types a.